# MD5 Implementation in C on Postgresql - reference error

Tags: c, linux, postgresql, md5

I am getting a very common error. However, I have looked at the multiple similar questions online and tried the linking process by adding `-lcrypto -lssl` to the end of `gcc`. However, I still get: `" Undefined reference to MD5"` every time we run. I am using MD5 as the Hash function. We use the  library and we are including it in the header of the program where I call it. Any insights would be really great!
The code for the makefile is as below:

```
CPP=gcc
OPTS= -Wall
#OPTS=-g -Wall
#-lcrypto and -lssl being added below 
LIBS=-lresolv -ldl -lm -lcrypto -lssl 
# Modify PSQLPATH if necesssary
#PSQLPATH=/home/alice/postgresql-9.3.2
PSQLPATH=/home/a/ambangra/postgresql-9.3.2
INCLUDE=-I$(PSQLPATH)/src/include     

# compiles your modified version of postgresql code 
assign2c: copyassign2 compile

# installs your modified version of postgresql code 
assign2i: copyassign2 install

# restores original version of postgresql code
restore: copyoriginal install

copyassign2:
    cp guc.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/utils/misc/guc.c
    cp globals.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/utils/init/globals.c
    cp hashjoin.h $(PSQLPATH)/src/include/executor/hashjoin.h
    cp nodeHash.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/executor/nodeHash.c
    cp nodeHashjoin.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/executor/nodeHashjoin.c
    cp explain.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/commands/explain.c

copyoriginal:
    cp Original-files/guc.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/utils/misc/guc.c
    cp Original-files/globals.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/utils/init/globals.c
    cp Original-files/hashjoin.h $(PSQLPATH)/src/include/executor/hashjoin.h
    cp Original-files/nodeHash.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/executor/nodeHash.c
    cp Original-files/nodeHashjoin.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/executor/nodeHashjoin.c
    cp Original-files/explain.c $(PSQLPATH)/src/backend/commands/explain.c

compile:
    cd $(PSQLPATH) && make 

install:
    cd $(PSQLPATH) && make && make install

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: adding -lcrypto should work. are you using openssl's md5?

Comment: Yes. I am including <openssl/md5> in the header. We have a makefile in PSQL to compile and run the program. So, I have added -lcrypto there as well. I am adding the code in the makefile in my question to give a better idea.

Comment: output compiling process to file and see if -lcrypto properly added to command of linking

Comment: What command tells us its linking?

Comment: manually  add -lcrypto  to the end of  command starting with gcc -o